# Save HTML5 canvas with images as an image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to save a canvas with images to PNG, but when I try this:

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var img = document.createElement('img');
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext ? myCanvas.getContext('2d') : null;
img.src = 'image.png';

img.onload = function () {  
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
}

var data = myCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
if (!window.open(data)) {
    document.location.href = data;
}
```

I only get a blank transparent image without the image. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put the `window.open` call in the load handler since this happens *asynchronously*.

```
img.onload = function () {  
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);

    var data = myCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    if (!window.open(data)) {
        document.location.href = data;
    }
}
```