# How to download filtered images by CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, filter

How is possible to download image after CSS filter methods?

Here is more about filters: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp

My point is to use JS and scrollers to filter uploaded images, but how to download that?

Thanks

Comment: Download to the user's computer or to yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save or download images directly, but you can render them in Canvas, then save from there.

You can find info abou that on : [Save HTML5 canvas with images as an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620763/save-html5-canvas-with-images-as-an-image)